# GNU C Compiler Warnings jenkis build.ros.org

Tags: ros, jenkins, ros-kinetic, build, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Warning when our package is build in Jenkins
http://build.ros.org/job/Kdev__ira_laser_tools__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/changes

but the information about the warning is not helpful

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344125/gnu-c-compiler-warnings-jenkis-build.ros.org/) by [pietrocolombo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32441/pietrocolombo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-14**:
Please add a verbatim copy-paste of the warning to your question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

resolve by adding this in CmakeList

`remove_definitions(-DDISABLE_LIBUSB-1.0)`

---

Originally posted by [pietrocolombo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32441/pietrocolombo/) with karma: 63 on 2020-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0